# Chrome states "Not Secure" when on record page with Lighting Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, security

When I navigate to a record with a Lightning Web Component, my chrome browser lists "Not Secure" in the hyperlink bar. How do I configure either the Salesforce instance or my Lightning Web Components to shore up security and prevent this security notification?

We are in Lightning Experience.

(Specific code examples can be provided upon request, but this is not specific to any one lwc - it appears to happen with all of them. All code including Apex with SOQL queries contains the "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" condition)

Comment: Can you please paste a screenshot of that and also of the screen that comes up when you click not secure. It is likely not related to apex or lwc.

Comment: Did you include any JS from third parties in your lwc?

Comment: @LeonardoPMacedo I did not